# Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview, actionsheetpicker

My application requires following things to be added in an action sheet.

- UIToolbar
- Button on UIToolbar
- UIPicker Control

I have included an image to understand my requirements.

[image]

Could you please explain, how this can be implemented?

Comment: Thank you for posting this interesting problem!

Comment: Instead of messing with the managing the actionSheet, pickerView, etc., I would recommend using [EAActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/EckyZero/EAActionSheetPickerDemo). It really cleans up your code a lot.

Comment: @eckyzero Unfortunately, the EAActionSheetPicker seem to be broken in iOS 7, there is a lot of errors all starting with "invalid context 0x0.".

Comment: of course its to good to be true ...fook me, y ios b so difficult

Comment: EAActionSheetPicker does no longer work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update for iOS 7**

[Apple docs for UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2): `UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy`

I recommend against trying to customize the contents of an ActionSheet, as it can lead to serious invalid context errors in iOS 7. I just spent a few hours working through this problem and ultimately decided to take a different approach. I replaced the call to show the action sheet with a modal view controller containing a simple tableview.

There are many ways to accomplish this. Here's one way that I just implemented in a current project. It's nice because I can reuse it between 5 or 6 different screens where I all users to select from a list of options.

1. Create a new UITableViewController subclass, `SimpleTableViewController`.
2. Create a UITableViewController in your storyboard (embedded in a navigation controller) and set its custom class to SimpleTableViewController.
3. Give the navigation controller for SimpleTableViewController a Storyboard ID of "SimpleTableVC".
4. In SimpleTableViewController.h, create an NSArray property that will represent the data in the table.
5. Also in SimpleTableViewController.h, create a protocol `SimpleTableViewControllerDelegate` with a required method `itemSelectedatRow:`, and a weak property called delegate of type `id<SimpleTableViewControllerDelegate>`. This is how we will pass the selection back to the parent controller.
6. In SimpleTableViewController.m, implement the tableview data source and delegate methods, calling `itemSelectedatRow:` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

This approach has the added benefit of being fairly reusable. To use, import the SimpleTableViewController class in your ViewController.h, conform to the SimpleTableViewDelegate, and implement the `itemSelectedAtRow:` method. Then, to open the modal just instantiate a new SimpleTableViewController, set the table data and delegate, and present it.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableVC"];
SimpleTableViewController *tableViewController = (SimpleTableViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
tableViewController.tableData = self.statesArray;
tableViewController.navigationItem.title = @"States";
tableViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I create a simple example and [posted it on github](https://github.com/kmc239/KMCModalTableView).

Also see [Showing actionsheet causes CGContext invalid context errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129091/showing-actionsheet-causes-cgcontext-invalid-context-errors).

Comment: Ahh iOS 7! You ruined everything which was developed till now. :(

Comment: @Kyle Can you expand your answer by telling what was your approach? Thanks

Comment: @DanielSanchez Updated with an alternative suggestion and code sample.

Comment: A much more elegant solution IMHO is to set your textfield's input view to UIPickerView and its accessory to UIToolbar. You can check out the QuickDialog project for an example.

Answer (score 111):

One more solution:

- no toolbar but a segmented control (eyecandy)

  ```
  UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                      delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

  [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

  CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

  UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
  pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
  pickerView.dataSource = self;
  pickerView.delegate = self;

  [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
  [pickerView release];

  UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
  closeButton.momentary = YES; 
  closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
  closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
  closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
  [closeButton release];

  [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

  [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
  ```

Comment: i am getting UIApplication may not respond to mainwindow warning and application terminates.

Comment: I'm trying to use the UIPickerView but haven't been able to integrate it into my app. I want the UIPickerView to be displayed on click of a button whose action is registered in MYViewController:UIViewController. In the action method I have put the above code of pickerview. what else should I do? Please help.

Comment: I changed [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication mainWindow]]; to make it work. [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; or [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar]; if you have a tabbar

Comment: Actually fredrik, you should use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]. Edited source to change that.

Comment: @Namratha If you want to display the picker view on button click,The best solution in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617164/picker-view-not-appearing-on-1st-attempt-of-button-click,Hope it will help you better :)

Comment: thanks for this post. the only thing I wasn't happy about was the use of UISegmentedController, which is not intended to be used as a single button (the result is a slightly blurry button on non-retina display). I was easily able to work around this by adding a toolbar with the done button at the top of the actionsheet, which works perfect.

Comment: has anyone used this in production code? no risk getting rejected?

Comment: @VanDuTran I figured it out. see solution below.

Comment: The ActionSheetPicker project mentioned by sickAnimations handles horizontal orientation just fine.

Comment: [Van Du Tran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/655857/van-du-tran)  - (void)dismissActionSheet:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{
    
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = (UIActionSheet*)[sender superview];
    
        [actionSheet  dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0
                                          animated:YES];
    }

Comment: UIActionSheet *actionSheet =  (UIActionSheet *)[(UIView *)sender superview];
        [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; might also work for dismissing the action sheet

Comment: Heads up: this causes many CGContext errors in iOS 7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129091/showing-actionsheet-causes-cgcontext-invalid-context-errors

Comment: @Kyle I totally agree with you. This answers is really old and shows bad coding practices. sorry that

Answer (score 75):

Even though this question is old, I'll quickly mention that I've thrown together an [ActionSheetPicker class](https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker) with a convenience function, so you can spawn an ActionSheet with a UIPickerView in one line. It's based on code from answers to this question.

Edit: It now also supports the use of a DatePicker and DistancePicker.

---

## UPD:

### This version is deprecated: use [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) instead.

[image: animation]

Comment: Super... using this in my app.

Comment: @Sick do i need to add your name in my project if i use your code, thanks

Comment: Hello, I'm using this class in my app and it works great. Thanks. I have a question. In the `ActionSheetDatePicker` mode, you can add multiple buttons to the toolbar on top. Is this possible with just normal `ActionSheetStringPicker` too?

Comment: Can it do multiple selection?

Comment: Its breaking in ios 7.1 :(

Answer (score 32):

Yep ! I finally Find it.

implement following code on your button click event, to pop up action sheet as given in the image of question.

```
UIActionSheet *aac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"How many?"
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIDatePicker *theDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
if(IsDateSelected==YES)
{
    theDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    theDatePicker.maximumDate=[NSDate date];
}else {
    theDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
}

self.dtpicker = theDatePicker;
[theDatePicker release];
[dtpicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

[aac addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
[aac addSubview:dtpicker];
[aac showInView:self.view];
[aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
```

Comment: hi sagar, thanks for the code, DatePickerDoneClick button event, how to declare it

thanks

Comment: sagar, how to dismiss the pop up action sheet, and add selected value into the text field

thanks

Comment: [aac dimisswithclickedindex] // something like this method.
( see I have placed a done button in action sheet & add done button target - selector & in selector place dimissal code.

Comment: thanks for reply sagar, i add [aac dismissWithClickedButtonIndex];
but i'm getting 
warning: 'UIActionSheet' may not respond to '-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex'

then i create new method for selector 'DatePickerDoneClick'

as below

- (void) DatePickerDoneClick
{
 NSLog(@"Done clicked");
        ratings.text = pickerView objectAtIndex:row]
}

what shall i do, so when i click the done button UIActionSheet(aac) dismiss and textfield(ratings.text) be filled with selected value from picker

thanks sagar

Comment: hi sagar, i able to update the text all, just can't dismiss the action sheet, even when click done button can trig, what shall i add into 

- (void) DatePickerDoneClick
{
 NSLog(@"Done clicked");
 NSInteger row = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    rat.text = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}

so action sheet dismiss

thanks

Comment: hi sagar, thanks, i'm able find to dismiss the action sheet,

thanks

Comment: @selector(DatePickerDoneClick) should be @selector(DatePickerDoneClick:)

Comment: @Spark is it possible to give some idea about getting the picker text.. thanks for your post+1

Comment: @Spark In order to dismiss it, I would have to make aac an ivar and call [_aac removeFromSuperview]; right?

Comment: This seem to be broken in iOS 7, it still works but Xcode gives a lot of runtime warnings like: "<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update."

Anyone have found a solution for this or is it Apple that doesn't like this solution and now want to get rid of it...?

Answer (score 10):

Marcio's excellent solution to this question was of great help to me in adding subviews of any kind to a UIActionSheet.

For reasons that are not (yet) entirely clear to me, the bounds of the UIActionSheet can only be set after it has been displayed; both sagar's and marcio's solutions successfully address this with a setBounds:CGRectMake(...) message being sent to the actionsheet **after** it is shown.

However, setting the UIActionSheet bounds after the sheet has been displayed creates a jumpy transition when the ActionSheet appeaars, where it "pops" into view, and then only scrolls in over the final 40 pixels or so.

When sizing a UIPickerView after adding subviews, I recommend wrapping the setBounds message sent to the actionSheet inside an animation block.  This will make the entrance of the actionSheet appear smoother.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];


// add one or more subviews to the UIActionSheet
// this could be a UIPickerView, or UISegmentedControl buttons, or any other 
// UIView.  Here, let's just assume it's already set up and is called 
// (UIView *)mySubView
[actionSheet addSubview:myView];

// show the actionSheet
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication mainWindow]];


// Size the actionSheet with smooth animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This is a great tip. Under ios 4 and later, this style of animation is "discouraged" though as per the docs. Under iOS 4 or later, try this instead: UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f 
                         delay:0 
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,485)];} 
                         completion:NULL];

Answer (score 9):

For those guys who are tying to find the DatePickerDoneClick function... here is the simple code to dismiss the Action Sheet. Obviously aac should be an ivar (the one which goes in your implmentation .h file)

```
- (void)DatePickerDoneClick:(id)sender{
    [aac dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't really understand why the `UIPickerView` is going inside a `UIActionSheet`. This seems to be a messy and hacky solution, which can be broken in a future iOS release. (I've had things like this break in an app before, where the `UIPickerView` wasn't being presented on the first tap and had to be retapped - weird quirks with the `UIActionSheet`).

What I did is simply implement a `UIPickerView` and then added it as a subview to my view, and animate it moving up as though it were being presented like an action sheet.

```
/// Add the PickerView as a private variable
@interface EMYourClassName ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *picker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *backgroundTapButton;

@end

///
/// This is your action which will present the picker view
///
- (IBAction)showPickerView:(id)sender {

    // Uses the default UIPickerView frame.
    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Place the Pickerview off the bottom of the screen, in the middle set the datasource delegate and indicator
    _picker.center = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height + _picker.frame.size.height);
    _picker.dataSource = self;
    _picker.delegate = self;
    _picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    // Create the toolbar and place it at -44, so it rests "above" the pickerview.
    // Borrowed from @Spark, thanks!
    UIToolbar *pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 44)];
    pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    // The action can whatever you want, but it should dimiss the picker.
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [_picker addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];

    // If you have a UITabBarController, you should add the picker as a subview of it
    // so it appears to go over the tabbar, not under it. Otherwise you can add it to 
    // self.view
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:_picker];

    // Animate it moving up
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        [_picker setCenter:CGPointMake(160, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 148)]; //148 seems to put it in place just right.
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // When done, place an invisible button on the view behind the picker, so if the
        // user "taps to dismiss" the picker, it will go away. Good user experience!
        self.backgroundTapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _backgroundTapButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [_backgroundTapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:_backgroundTapButton];
    }];

}

// And lastly, the method to hide the picker.  You should handle the picker changing
// in a method with UIControlEventValueChanged on the pickerview.
- (void)backgroundTapped:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        _picker.center = CGPointMake(160, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height + _picker.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_picker removeFromSuperview];
        self.picker = nil;
        [self.backgroundTapButton removeFromSuperview];
        self.backgroundTapButton = nil;
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Have you found this works fine with iOS 7?

Comment: +1 for great simple picker view that animated to screen. But you have an error in the code. The view backgroundTapButton spawns on top of picker view and there for blocks the picker view from user interaction. what u really mean to do was to make this view on the remaining screen space that the picker view doesn't already fill... (u can't make a view behind the picker view like you mean to )

Answer (score 7):

To add to marcio's awesome solution, `dismissActionSheet:` can be implemented as follows.

1. Add an ActionSheet object to your .h file, synthesize it and reference it in your .m file.
2. Add this method to your code.

   ```
   - (void)dismissActionSheet:(id)sender{
     [_actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
     [_myButton setTitle:@"new title"]; //set to selected text if wanted
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is best way to do it.

[ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)

Its pretty much what everyone suggest, but uses blocks, which is a nice touch!

Comment: Well if you read above you will see that this ActionSheetPicker class came about in the first place, due to this thread.  So yeah that is the best way, thanks to the accepted solution (¬_¬).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how/4622337#4622337

Comment: Looks like apple is about to start enforcing their rule that actionsheets should not be subclassed as I'm getting this error message - " <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update."

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 8, you can't, it doesn't work because Apple changed internal implementation of `UIActionSheet`. Please refer to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Subclassing Notes
>
> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, **nor**
>   **should you add views to its hierarchy**. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the approach taken by Wayfarer and flexaddicted, but found (like aZtral) that it did not work as the backgroundTapButton was the only element that was responding to user interaction.  This led me to put all three of his subviews: _picker, _pickerToolbar and backgroundTapButton inside a containing view (popup) which was then animated on and off the screen.  I also needed a Cancel button on the _pickerToolbar.  Here are the relevant code elements for the popup view (you need to supply your own picker data source and delegate methods).

```
#define DURATION            0.4
#define PICKERHEIGHT        162.0
#define TOOLBARHEIGHT       44.0

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView        *popup;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView  *picker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIToolbar     *pickerToolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton      *backgroundTapButton;
@end

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // These are ivars for convenience
    rect = self.view.bounds;
    topNavHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    bottomNavHeight = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
    navHeights = topNavHeight + bottomNavHeight;
}

-(void)showPickerView:(id)sender {
    [self createPicker];
    [self createToolbar];

    // create view container
    _popup = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, topNavHeight, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - navHeights)];
    // Initially put the centre off the bottom of the screen
    _popup.center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0, rect.size.height + _popup.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    [_popup addSubview:_picker];
    [_popup insertSubview:_pickerToolbar aboveSubview:_picker];

    // Animate it moving up
    // This seems to work though I am not sure why I need to take off the topNavHeight
    CGFloat vertCentre = (_popup.frame.size.height - topNavHeight) / 2.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION animations:^{
        // move it to a new point in the middle of the screen
        [_popup setCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0, vertCentre)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // When done, place an invisible 'button' on the view behind the picker,
        // so if the user "taps to dismiss" the picker, it will go away
        self.backgroundTapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _backgroundTapButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _popup.frame.size.width, _popup.frame.size.height);
        [_backgroundTapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_popup insertSubview:_backgroundTapButton belowSubview:_picker];
        [self.view addSubview:_popup];
    }];
}

-(void)createPicker {
    // To use the default UIPickerView frame of 216px set frame to CGRectZero, but we want the 162px height one
    CGFloat     pickerStartY = rect.size.height - navHeights - PICKERHEIGHT;
    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, pickerStartY, rect.size.width, PICKERHEIGHT)];
    _picker.dataSource = self;
    _picker.delegate = self;
    _picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    // Otherwise you can see the view underneath the picker
    _picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _picker.alpha = 1.0f;
}

-(void)createToolbar {
    CGFloat     toolbarStartY = rect.size.height - navHeights - PICKERHEIGHT - TOOLBARHEIGHT;
    _pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolbarStartY, rect.size.width, TOOLBARHEIGHT)];
    [_pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelAction:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelButton];

    // Flexible space to make the done button go on the right
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    // The done button
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneButton];
    [_pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
}

// The method to process the picker, if we have hit done button
- (void)doneAction:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION animations:^{
        _popup.center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0, rect.size.height + _popup.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { [self destroyPopup]; }];
    // Do something to process the returned value from your picker
}

// The method to process the picker, if we have hit cancel button
- (void)cancelAction:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION animations:^{
        _popup.center = CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0, rect.size.height + _popup.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { [self destroyPopup]; }];
}

-(void)destroyPopup {
    [_picker removeFromSuperview];
    self.picker = nil;
    [_pickerToolbar removeFromSuperview];
    self.pickerToolbar = nil;
    [self.backgroundTapButton removeFromSuperview];
    self.backgroundTapButton = nil;
    [_popup removeFromSuperview];
    self.popup = nil;
}
```