# UIActionSheet showInView give warning : invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, datepicker, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to show UIActionSheet in `self.view.parentview`. But I got below warning while running

```
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

Code is below

```
self.dobActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
[self.dobActionSheet addSubview:self.doneForActionSheet];
[self.dobActionSheet addSubview:self.cancelForActionSheet];
[self.dobActionSheet addSubview:self.dobDatepicker];
[self.dobActionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view];
```

I've put breakpoint. but get this warning in this line `[self.dobActionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view];`..

I've try to present in `Viewcontroller` which is `embedded in tabbarController` at first index. That's why, try to present with `parentViewController.view` instead `self.view`

**Note:** I've seen as same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497948/cgcontextsetfillcolorwithcolor-invalid-context-0x0-this-is-a-serious-error). But couldn't find answer for this.

Comment: Try with [self.dobActionSheet showInView:self.view];

Comment: I couldn't do this. Because this viewcontroller is embedded in tabbarcontroller at first index. Is it correct way to do it? Any way tried this, but got same error.. !!

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19111512/544265

Comment: @c0ming thanks for your link. I've tried this but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"Ok"];
```

**instead of nil value, use @""**

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@""
destructiveButtonTitle:nil
otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Action sheet show title.. So I tried with single space as title. It's working. see my answer.. thanks +1 for U:)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue from @Sunny shah answers. I've tried with his answer but have `title` on action sheet. Instead I tried with below code.(Title name as single space).

```
self.dobActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@" " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
```