# UIView transitions present modal view at the bottom

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, model-view-controller

I need to display a UIView/UIViewController when the user taps a button and the modal view should appear just like how the key board appears from the bottom bar when you edit text in a UITextField. Using the following code, I get to show it as a pop up.

```
[self presentModalViewController:child animated:YES];
```

How to make it appear like the keyboard?

---

I understad modal views cover the entire screen. But I *really* want a view that covers only half the screen. So, please tell me why this doesn't work

```
MyController *controller = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,44,768,264);
[controller view].frame = frame;
contoller.delegate = self;
[[self view] addSubView:[controller view]];
[controller release];
```

I am trying to add a sub view to my current view and make it appear where the keyboard appears.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `child.modalTransitionStyle == UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`.

(And a model view controller always cover the whole screen. If you just need to cover half of the screen like the keyboard, you need to put the view controller's view as a subview of the main view, then animate it in manually with animation blocks.)

Comment: that helps. thank you. can you please elaborate on the animations for sliding from the bottom bar?

Comment: @Dave: Just set the transition style and present the modal view controller.

Comment: ok. I set the transitionstyle to CoverVertical and changed PresentationStyle from FormSheet to PageSheet. It is animating just like how I wanted but it covers the whole page. Is there a way to resize the view?

Comment: @Dave: A modal view controller always cover the whole page.

Comment: well then I guess I need to add a sub view, in that case, right? Please see my updated question [above].

Comment: @Dave: Adding a view controller *not* as subview of a window or view controller can cause problems. Can you *not* use a view controller?

Comment: you are right, Kenny. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450594/uiview-transition-and-animation

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but an answer to this is to use a UIActionSheet.

It won't present a View Controller, but you can present custom views that only cover a portion of the screen.

Check out this question for more information

[Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)