# UIPickerView in UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, uialertview

Is it possible to put UIPickerView into UIAlertView?If yes, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example [here](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2009/07/15/look-uialertview-is-dating-uitableview.html) of adding a UITableView, you should be able to adapt it to suit your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

but 
in
UIActionSheet

```
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerMoney];
```

## Heading

Answer (score 1):

Nope. But you can embed a picker in a UIActionSheet, which lets you give the user a nice slide up and slide down animation when showing or dismissing the picker.

There are a couple of good examples of the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634242/hiding-showing-uipickerview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how).

Answer (score -2):

No, [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/addButtonWithTitle:) only has buttons and you can only set their titles.