# display done button on UIPickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have written the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
categoryPickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
categoryPickerView.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:categoryPickerView];
categoryPickerView.delegate=self;
categoryPickerView.tag=1;
```

and called this method to hide picker view

```
- (IBAction)hidePickerView:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
    categoryPickerView.transform = transfrom;
    categoryPickerView.alpha = categoryPickerView.alpha * (-1) + 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

My problem is that I want to display a "Done" button on a picker view and the picker view should hide on button click.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use this code,

```
UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(changeDateFromLabel:)];
toolBar.items = @[barButtonDone];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[pickerView addSubview:toolBar];
//(or)pickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

and set button action method for `changeDateFromLabel:`

```
-(void)changeDateFromLabel:(id)sender
{
   [[your UI Element] resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: can you see the toolbar?

Comment: do i need to change in CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)  @sathiamoorthy

Comment: have you tried inputAccessoryView?. instead of adding in pickerview. For example, use this --> pickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar; instead of  [pickerView addSubview:toolBar];

Comment: i tried using pickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar; but it is giving error assignment to read only property @sathiamoorthy

Comment: try this, works for me.
yourUITextField.inputView = pickerView; yourUITextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

toolBar is part of input accessory view of the text field, not the picker view.

Comment: The bar and the button appear, but the button is not clickable, like something transparent covers it. And InputAccesoryView is readonly.

Comment: I suppose PickerView catches touch event and button is not clickable. This works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883388/display-done-button-on-uipickerview/29776876#29776876

Comment: @Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez my swift code has same issue. any solution

Comment: Done button doesn't work unless you put the toolbar and picker in a container view.

Answer (score 17):

You can create view and add toolbar with "Done" button and UIPickerView as subviews

```
- (void)createInputView {
    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 44)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(doneClicked)];
    toolBar.items = @[flex, barButtonDone];
    barButtonDone.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolBar.frame.size.height, screenWidth, 200)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;


    UIView *inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, toolBar.frame.size.height + picker.frame.size.height)];
    inputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [inputView addSubview:picker];
    [inputView addSubview:toolBar];

    textField.inputView = inputView;
}

- (void)doneClicked {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way i guess. 
sathiamoorthy's answer does not work properly as the done button doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the UIToolbar as the accessory view:
Try with this:

```
#pragma mark - PickerView for Location Selection

- (UIPickerView *)locationsPicker {
    if ( locationsPicker == nil ) {
        locationsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        locationsPicker.delegate = self;
        locationsPicker.dataSource = self;
        locationsPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    }
    return locationsPicker;
}

- (UIToolbar *)accessoryView {
    if ( accessoryView == nil ) {
        accessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
                                       UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(onLocationSelection)];
        [accessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton]];
    }
    return accessoryView;
}

- (void)onLocationSelection {
    NSInteger row = [self.locationsPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if ( [Location isFirstResponder] ) {
       NSLog(@"%@", [listOfLocations objectAtIndex:row]);
        [Location resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Copy-pasteable solution!**

This works in iOS 10 (and probably other versions too)  I wrote this code on 9/4/2017.

I needed to combine other answers to get what I wanted, which was a `Cancel` button, `Done` button, and a picker view that would show/hide on the tap of a button.  Ignore the fact that my screenshot only has one item in the picker.. I only have one item in my array.  I've tested multiple items, it works fine.

[image]

*Disclaimer!  I have tested and used this code.  I generalized the names in my example, so I apologize in advance if I missed one and they property names don't line up.*

**In order to have a pickerView that appears on the tap of a button, you need to create a dummyTextField (of type `UITextField` anywhere in your view controller**.  This is because `UIPickerView`'s are designed to work with UITextFields.  To mimic showing and hiding of the picker, your button taps need to call the dummyTextField's `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder` methods.  (examples are below)

**Step one**

Create a custom data source class.  MyObj is the class you  want to have items show up in the picker for.

In .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class myObj;

@interface PickerDataSource : NSObject <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyObj *selectedObject;
@end
```

In .m:

```
#import "PickerDataSource.h"
#import "MyObj.h"

@implementation PickerDataSource

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.selectedObject = mySourceArray[row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return mySourceArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return ((MyObj *)mySourceArray[row]).myTitle;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int sectionWidth = 300;
    return sectionWidth;
}

@end
```

**Step two** In your view controller, import custom data source, delegate, and set properties: (You *must* include the text field delegate!)

```
#import "PickerDataSource.h"

@interface MyViewController () <UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) PickerDataSource *pickerDataSource;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *picker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *dummyTextField;
@end
```

**Step three**

In your `viewDidLoad`, call `[self setupPicker];` (you'll create this method next)

**Step four**

Create `setupPicker`

```
- (void)setupPicker {
    // init custom picker data source
    self.pickerDataSource = [PickerDataSource new];
    // init custom picker
    self.picker = [UIPickerView new];
    // set the picker's dataSource and delegate to be your custom data source
    self.picker.dataSource = self.pickerDataSource;
    self.picker.delegate = self.pickerDataSource;
    self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    // next step is to write this configure method getting called here
    [self configurePickerSubviews];

    // lastly, add the dummyTextField to your view.
    [self.view addSubview:self.dummyTextField];
}
```

**Step five**

Create `configurePickerSubviews`

```
- (void)configurePickerSubviews {
    // A UIPickerView must be added as an inputView to a UITextField in order to be displayed on button tap
    // So you need to create a dummyTextField to do so.
    self.dummyTextField = [UITextField new];

    // Create a toolbar to add a done button
    UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,44)];
    [toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(locationPressed)];

    // Create a flex space so that done button will be right aligned
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissPicker)];
    toolBar.items = @[cancel, flex, done];
    done.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self.picker addSubview:toolBar];

    // Create an input view to add picker + done button as subviews
    UIView *inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, self.picker.frame.size.height + 44)];
    [self.picker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, inputView.frame.size.width, inputView.frame.size.height)];
    inputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [inputView addSubview:self.picker];
    [inputView addSubview:toolBar];

    // Set custom inputView as container for picker view
    self.dummyTextField.inputView = inputView;

    // Hiding the textfield will hide the picker
    [self.dummyTextField setHidden:YES];
}
```

**Step six**

Configure the `PickerDataSource` so that it is fetching the data you want to display from your source array.

**Step 7**

Click `Run`!

Answer (score 2):

The `UIToolbar` with the 'Done' button should be added to the `inputAccessoryView` of the view that **becomes first responder**. As the `UIView` class inherits from `UIResponder`, any view can potentially contain an `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView`. So instead of manually performing the animations programmatically, you could use the default animation behaviour that comes with the UIResponder's keyboard show/hide animation.

1. Subclass a `UIView` and override the `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` properties and make them `readwrite`. In this example, I will subclass a `UITableViewCell`.

   ```
   // FirstResponderTableViewCell.h
   @interface FirstResponderTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
   @property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIView *inputView;
   @property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
   @end
   ```
2. Override `canBecomeFirstResponder` in your subclass' implementation.

   ```
   // FirstResponderTableViewCell.m
   - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
       return YES;
   }
   ```
3. In your view controller, create and assign the picker view and input accessory toolbar

   ```
   // MyViewController.m
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
       UIToolbar *accessoryToolbar = [UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
       // Configure toolbar .....

       // note: myFirstResponderTableViewCell is an IBOutlet to a static cell in storyboard of type FirstResponderTableViewCell
       self.myFirstResponderTableViewCell.inputView = pickerView;
       self.myFirstResponderTableViewCell.inputAccessoryView = accessoryToolbar;
   }
   ```
4. Don't forget to assign first responder to the view when required (e.g. inside - `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`)

   ```
   [self.myFirstResponderTableViewCell becomeFirstResponder];
   ```

Hope this helps.

Reference: http://blog.swierczynski.net/2010/12/how-to-create-uipickerview-with-toolbar-above-it-in-ios/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
UIPickerView *cityPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cityPicker.delegate = self;
cityPicker.dataSource = self;
[cityPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
txtText.inputView = cityPicker;
// Create done button in UIPickerView
UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];
[mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
txtText.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;  // set the toolbar as input accessory view  for uitextfield, not the pickerview.
```

http://technopote.com/how-to-make-multiple-uipickerview-in-a-single-view/

Comment: What if i not used textField but on open picke on IBAction

Answer (score 0):

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDelegate>
 {
UIPickerView *myPickerView;
NSArray *namesArray ;

 }
 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
    namesArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];
   [self popoverWithInformation];


  }

 -(void)popoverWithInformation
 {
UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];



[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];


myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
CGRect pickerRect = myPickerView.bounds;
myPickerView.bounds = pickerRect;
myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216);

UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 300)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[popoverView addSubview:myPickerView];

[popoverView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[self.view addSubview:popoverView];
 }
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


 }

 // tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
 -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

  return namesArray.count;
 }

 // tell the picker how many components it will have
 -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return 1;
 }

 // tell the picker the title for a given component
 -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {




return namesArray[row];
 }

 // tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
 -(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
int sectionWidth = 300;

return sectionWidth;
 }

 -(void)pickerDone:(id)sender
 {


 }
 -(void)pickerCancel:(id)sender
 {


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 try this,

```
  func setToolBar() {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 44))
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.donePicker))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton],animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
        picker.addSubview(toolBar)
      }  

  @objc func donePicker() {
    // hide keypad
  }
```