# how to add done button on uipicker view

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have written the following code on button click action in order to create ui picker view

```
- (IBAction)selectbtn:(id)sender {
    pickerview = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 40, 300, 300)];
    pickerview.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerview.hidden = NO;
    pickerview.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerview];
}
```

Here are my picker delegates

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;


}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.jsonresultarr.count;


}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

//    return [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_Id"];
  //  NSObject *companyId = [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_Id"];
    NSObject *companyName = [[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_Name"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", companyName, nil];




}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.Textbox.text=[[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Company_Name"];
    [self.pickerview removeFromSuperview];


}
```

My problem is that i want to show done button on uipicker view whose function is to set selected value in my text field. How i can make it. Thanx in advance

Comment: use `UIToolbar` and add `UIBarbuttonItem` in it. add toolbar above your picker.

Comment: @Chinttu -Maddy- Ramani will you please tell how as i am new in ios

Comment: check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883388/display-done-button-on-uipickerview)

Comment: add bar button as you add picker to view in  button action remove the view

Comment: And how can i set date in textfield ?

Comment: @ismail main thing i want to make an action behind this button?

Comment: Will you please tell me the correct method...

Comment: take one custom button, add action as target to the button and then add this button to the barbutton as initwithcustomview and set the frame where u want it in the view, do what you want in your custombutton action.

Comment: I created one programmatically. Here is a [well documented example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047257/3634990)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this . first add UIView in your self.view. add `UIPickerView` and `UIToolBar` init. and bind IBAction method with UIBarButtonItem. Please check attach screenshot.

[image]

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: try this. it will help you. if you didn't find your answer.

Comment: @MishalAwan if any answer is helpful to you then please mark as an answer so it is useful for other.

Comment: It's nice standard solution. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UIBarButtonItem` && `UIToolbar`

```
// add a toolbar with Done button
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouched:)];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];
self.pickerViewTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

**Triggered the picker view when click on Done Button**

```
- (void)doneTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    // hide the picker view
    [self.pickerViewTextField resignFirstResponder];

    // perform some action
}
```

and you can get selected value in `didSelectRow` delegate method.

Comment: than add UITapGestureRecognizer to UIBarButtonItem and call doneTouched method with UITapGestureRecognizer parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
  UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(done)];
 cancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
[cancelButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-PickerView.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50)];
    NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton,doneButton,nil];
[toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
self.textfield1.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

where is done method is as below

```
-(void)done{
 self.textfield1.text =[Array objectAtIndex:];
// for you it 
//self.Textbox.text=[[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:[PickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] objectForKey:@"Company_Name"];
}
```

and cancel method is

```
-(void)cancel{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: are you change @selector(done) with your button click action as above replace done with your action

Comment: means ?? what you want ti say.. u can post solution here

Comment: which action you want

Comment: When i click on this button selected value of picker view will set in uitextfield

Comment: did your  -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component this delegate call or any one of them. if not check that you add delegets in .h file

Comment: if you done with that and them also it not work then i give you another solution

Comment: ahan... this method is called but when i click on done button Self action on it is not called...

Comment: so wt i mean to say in above code replace @selector(done) with@selector(XXX)where XXX is your button self action and in that write   row = [repeatPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
self.Textbox.text=[[self.jsonresultarr objectAtIndex:row];

Comment: Will you please post this solution i am unable to get it ?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use this method(for ios8)

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil    
destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    txtPriorityTemp=myTextField;
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

    alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                          message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    //pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30);
    UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 305.0f, 44.f)];
    toolView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-headerNew.png"]];
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(220, 5, 70, 30);
    UIButton *selButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
    //[selButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_bgnew.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selButton addTarget: self
                  action: @selector(dismissActionSheet:)
        forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    selButton.tag= myTextField.tag+10;
    [toolView addSubview:selButton];
    [alertController.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [alertController.view addSubview:toolView];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```