# Can I click tableview cell show picker?

Tags: ios, label, tableview, cell, uipickerview

I establish a tableview , but I want to click direct cell show the picker to select.

Then the selected value will show in the cell label component.

But I had try to `labelName.text = picker`. or call picker in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` . It's not showing the picker.

my code is below

```
    -(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MotDeteTableViewCell";
        cell = (MotDeteTableViewCell*)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if( cell == nil )
        {
            cell = [[MotDeteTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }
        cell.motTableTitleLabel.text = [tableDatasAry  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if( indexPath.row == 0)
        {

      }
        else if ( indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            myLb = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_motTableView.frame.size.width -50 , 0.0, 70.0, 40.0) ];

                 // -------  I expect click the picker value will show in myLb label
            myLb.text = @"picker will show value"; 

            [cell addSubview:myLb];

        }



        return cell;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    switch (indexPath.row) {


            case 0:
                break;

            case 1:
                 // -------- I had try put settingPickeProperty in here or viewdidload
                [self settingPickeProperty];

                break;
          default:
                break;
        }
    }

    #pragma mark -  settting picker datas
    -(void) settingPickeProperty
    {
        picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        picker  .delegate = self;
        picker  .dataSource = self;
        [ picker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

        // -------if i use textfield the picker had correct show. but i want to click        cell show the picker, I don't know how to set  xxxx = picker;
        _pickertf.inputView =  picker  ;

        UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
        mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];

        NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
       [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];


        [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
        [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
        // ------ if use textfield had correct...
        _pickertf.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;

    }


    -(void)pickerDoneClicked
    {
        NSLog(@"Done Clicked");

    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:        (NSInteger)component
    {
        return [titleAry count];
    }


    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return [titleAry objectAtIndex:row];
    }


    - (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {

    }
```

It's my code offer every reference.

How to achieve click tableview cell to show the picker then select picker value show in myLb?

Comment: at didSelect Method you have selected row index. so you can put code of open picker by select particular cell of table view.

Comment: I had try to put [self settingPickeProperty]; part in select row index. but when i click the cell . It's not show the picker. And I don't know how to set   label =  picker? thanks .

Comment: @NitinGohel he is selecting the 2nd row. See `switch (indexPath.row)`

Comment: @dickfala are you able to log anything on that selected row

Comment: oh i see take a look this how to show pickerview  first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634242/hiding-showing-uipickerview

Comment: @dickfala where are you adding pickerView as the subView? I am not seeing it anywhere.

Comment: that's the poin @dickfala not adding pickerview and set frame also

Comment: @ Himanshu Joshi  I had trace in settingPickeProperty method . If I put  [self settingPickeProperty]; in  case 1: [self settingPickeProperty]; break; the programe had enter the method . It had show my log.

Comment: you can use my library: https://github.com/hijamoya/PickerViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the `pickerView` anywhere.

If you want to add in the current view, just use

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

picker.delegate = self;
picker.dataSource = self;
[picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[self.view addSubView:picker];
```

Comment: If I set textfield  . the picker will show when i click the textfield. ( _pickertf.inputView =  picker  ;)  But If I will set on tableview cell when user click. I don't know how to set this part. And  I had try to add [self.view addSubView:picker]; it's will show error. below: No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView:'   thanks

Comment: What is the base class in which you are adding the picker?

Comment: the effect is click picker will show. not always show on the view.

Comment: my base class is extends UIViewController

Comment: So what is this **No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView:'** ?

Comment: Did you used UIPicker `delegates` and `datasource` protocols?

Comment: yes, I have add protocols. If i try to use textfield, the picker will show  when i click textfield. So the picker program maybe not problem. The problem is on  _pickertf.inputView =  picker  ; here. If  i use textfield , the picker is set  _pickertf.inputview = picker. If I want to set click on the cell. I don't know how to set xxx = picker or other implement method. thank you~

Comment: _pickertf is my test textfield.

Comment: So basically you want the selected value from picker in textfield?

Comment: NO.. I have a label in the tableview cell. I want to click tableview cell jump to picker . Then after select picker value click done. It's will show value in the label.  TextField(_pickertf) just I try to know picker program is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you need to show picker value in selected table cell label.

So following steps may help you if cells are constant; for example just three cells.

You just not need to dequeue the cell and then try to set the value.