# only show half screen of controller using presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

i have a UIViewController that is only about 260px tall(or at least the area i want viewable is 260 approx. height) and really just has a picker on it and  a done button.  I'm calling presentModalViewController to display it but its showing the whole view, when really i only want to show the picker and the done button bar above the picker, 
not the black above the bar
, is there a way to show only this and not the whole view behind the picker when it is presented ?

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/1754/picker.jpg](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/1754/picker.jpg)

not too much for code here, ....

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tipPickerController];

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

let me know if i should post more code to get help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct answer to your question:
You don't have to use a full screen view (320 X 480). You might set the view for the exact size that you need (without the black part on the top).

My suggestion:
Set the view for full screen, but in addition set a transparent color for your top level view (instead of black).
This way the original view won't be interactive while the picker is visible...

Answer (score 0):

I am on a quest for the same thing. I found these resources.

[How to make a UIPickerView slide half way up the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147933/how-to-make-a-uipickerview-slide-half-way-up-the-screen)

[Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

The short answer is that a modal view controller is not what you want to use for this. It will work on an iPad but on an iPhone/iPod the modal view controller kills the first view when you display it. That is why it is black. I dont have it working yet but I think these resources are just the think to help.

Hope it helps.