# How to make a UIPickerView slide half way up the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

[image]

when someone clicks clothing, I want the UIPickerView to slide up as in the example as follows:
[image]

Can someone show a code sample please?

Comment: Have you tried creating an action sheet and embedding a picker view into that?

Comment: no that is the first time I heard of it. That is cool!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as dsc and Jason said, if you are using tableview, use its delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath , in it call an pickerview in an actionsheet.

To know how to call an pickerview in an actionsheet, check this link:
[Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

Comment: Looks like apple is about to start enforcing their rule that actionsheets should not be subclassed as I'm getting this error message - " <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update."

Answer (score 7):

**Update**:
This version is deprecated: use ActionSheetPicker instead.

You can use animation if you want a "sliding" effect

```
[pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake([[self view] frame].origin.x, [[self view] frame].origin.y + 480.0, [[self view] frame].size.width, [[self view] frame].size.height)];
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[pickerView setFrame: yourDesiredEndFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It's not tested but will give you an idea

Answer (score 6):

I have been looking for a solution to this as well. What I found was this:
https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker

There is a sample project in the zip file that demonstrates how nicely it works.

Enjoy!

---

### Update:

**This version is deprecated: use [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) instead.**

Comment: Is there also an ARC compatible version available?

Comment: Just go through the code and take out all the release and autorelease lines. Five minutes tops.