# UIPicker in Actionsheet

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement a UIpicker with numeric values in a Actionsheet on a text box event. When the user touches the text box, i want the UIpicker to pop up and allow a user to select a value. Do i have to declare the values in a array or is there some other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, you just have to create a UIPickerView inside the ActionSheet.

Here's a good answer for the same question:
[Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

Also, you could use the class I wrote, [ActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker), which creates an ActionSheet with a UIPickerView and calls back with the selected value.

Answer (score -2):

[UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can only contain a title (optional) and buttons. It cannot display a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).

Comment: But i have seen a lot of articles on this site where UIPickerView have been implemented in a UIActionSheet. Though none of them actually seem to address the scenario that i mentioned.

Comment: You can do it by adding a UIPickerView as a subview of an ActionSheet view (see my answer).