# UIPickerView inside an action sheet is not responsive from bottom half

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I created a `UIPickerView` inside an `UIActionSheet`, using the following tutorial:
[Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

I've noticed that the `UIPickerView` does not respond to touches below the bottom half of the `UIPicker`.  Perhaps *just* below the selection bar, but not any more below.

Has anyone had any similar experiences and resolved them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently where I was presenting 3 options and a cancel.  The lower 3 buttons seemed about half a button out of alignment.  I had to click inbetween the buttons to get them to operate.  It all depended on where I was presenting the action sheet from.  If you have a TabBarController you should present the action sheet from there:

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
```

If you just have the view itself, with perhaps a navbar then presenting it from the view is fine:

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

In my case I had a tab bar for the iphone and not for the ipad version so I did this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
} else {
    [actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
}
```

It's not clear from the UIActionSheet reference documentation but it might be wise to present the action sheet from the 'front' most controller that is sensible.  So if there is a toolbar at the bottom present it from that.  These restrictions do not appear to apply to the iPad as action sheets are presented inside popovers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had a very similar problem; in my case, the action sheet (which I was showing in view self.view) looked fine, but the Cancel button didn't work in the part that overlapped the tab bar.  Changing the inView parameter to self.tabBarController.view fixed it.  (Note: in my case I didn't need to use parentViewController... check your own view hierarchy to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

Hey go to XIB and try selecting the UIPickerView and Then Go to "Layout" Menu and "Bring To Front" Hope this helps!!