# iPhone: Best way for user to select options in a manner similar to a HTML select?

Tags: iphone, ios, select

I'm currently coding an iPhone app and i need to simulate a HTML select.

The app is a port of a web application which allows the user to select different units of measurement. For example, a user can select 'Millimetres' or 'Inches'. This is nice and simple in HTML as a select is perfect for the job, but how do i present this choice to the user of an iPhone app as there is no such thing as a select in UIKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest option (and the standard one used for such things) is a [UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html).

If you're after sample code, see the "Related sample code" section in the header of the above linked document.

In terms of presentation, you could use a [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to present the UIPickerView - there's a good question/answer already for this at [Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

Comment: I'm guessing you present this in a modal window? If so what is usually the control which shows it?

Comment: @Gary Willoughby I've updated my answer. You could use a UIActionSheet as the modal dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the UIPickerView:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPickerView