# in iPhone can we use UiPickerview as pop-up item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In iPhone App can we use UIpickerView as a pop-Up Mentu?
Like in Action sheet it appears as pop-up item can we have similar kind of thing for PickerView in iphone App ?

Please Help and Suggest,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend marcio's solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how).