# how to modify this code

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I read the post [Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

I want to add data to the uipicker view from nsarray , specially I have two buttons that they will call different two uipickerview , so I cannot use the delegate of uipickerview

also what is the code to clise this uipickerview

any suggestion please

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand, please rephrase it and expand on just what your scenario is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:
```

If you use that method you are acctually being passed the appropriate pickerview... so you can work out what pickerview you are dealing with from that. Its the same with most of the other delegate methods. So use that to work out what picker view you are dealing with and change the content accordingly.

To get rid of the actionsheet you can do:

```
[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```