# How to add a UITableView to a UIPickerView on the same view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview, uipickerview

I am trying to make an app with a UIPickerView and UITableView on the same view. I have the PickerView done and it works. But, I can't figure out how to connect the PickerView generated results to the tableView at the bottom of the view. The Picker iterates through user selected variables and I want the tableview to be populated with the results from the picker. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the UIPicker and UITable working, but need to know how I would get the user generated data to populate the tableview. Right now, I have two separate views working separately but not together.

Comment: When I say that I want to get the "user generated data", I mean I want to pull a new array I made from the values the user picked from the picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thanks to Sukas and many hours of hard work.

How did I add a UITableView to a UIPickerView on the same view.

First I made a UIViewController with no nib. I made the UIPickerView and UITableView programmatically in -(void)loadView.

PickerView and TableView were made into subviews of the UIView.

Important Part: In the DidSelectRow in Component method -- I added [self.table reloadData];

(This is the way I found to get the arrays from my component methods into my tableView methods)

Also, In the DidSelectRow in Component method I removed all objects from the arrays I created to hold the wheel selections. I made two arrays to hold the wheel selections and at different parts of the code I had to removeAllObjects from them, so that I got a new empty array every time the wheel changed and the tableview could be repopulated with new information.

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Links

first add your pickerview then
[Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

then in pickerview didSelectrow - Update your content in tableview like lblText.text = [yourArray objectatindex:row] , [self.tableview reloadData];

refer this

http://blog.originalfunction.com/index.php/2010/02/uitableview-uipickerview-with-core-data/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry. No, it doesn't help. I don't need an UIActionSheet.

Comment: Also, the UITableView won't even take an array's variables from the viewdidLoad or the loadview methods. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but some assistance would be appreciated!