# Help With UIDatePicker In UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I used some modified code found from another question on this website.

I am not sure however exactly what `theDatePicker` and `dtpicker` are.  I need to declare them but I don't know exactly if they are supposed to be a UIDatePicker and why there are two of them.  Can anyone figure it out? Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)dateButtonPressed1
{
    UIActionSheet *aac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    self.dtpicker = theDatePicker;
    [theDatePicker release];
    [dtpicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [aac addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
    [aac addSubview:dtpicker];
    [aac showInView:self.view];
    [aac setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
}
```

Link to original question where I found code: [Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

Comment: faisal, what exactly you want to do... because in this code there are many things that may of no use to you. do you want toolbar and datepicker on actionsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIActionSheet *dateActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
        [dateActionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [dateActionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [dateActionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 383)];
        [dateActionSheet release];
```

Then after you have to write in the ActionSheet Delegate's this below method:

```
#define kPickerTag 200
#define SelectButtonIndex 1
#define CancelButtonIndex 2
-(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 116)];
    [pickerView setTag:kPickerTag];

    [pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        if(!(strPrintDate == @""))
        {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM-dd-yyyy"];
            NSDate *pickerdate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.strPrintDate];
            [pickerView setDate:pickerdate animated:YES];
            [dateFormat release];
        }
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

    [pickerView release];

    NSArray *subViews = [actionSheet subviews];

    [[subViews objectAtIndex:SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 75, 46)];
    [[subViews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(225, 5, 85, 46)];
```