# How to create Iphone alert with items selection?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to create such alert for IPhone?

[image: Item Selection in Android]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For doing same you have to go with custom UIAlertView, embedded with UITableView. For doing so either [**this**](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/) or [**this**](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/10/10/embedding-uitables-into-uialertviews/) will guide you very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

For this you just need to create view- which consists uiview, tableview and a buttons.
Code for CustomAlertView.

```
UIView-AlertAnimations.h                    // user defined class


@interface UIView(AlertAnimations)

- (void)doPopInAnimation;
- (void)doPopInAnimationWithDelegate:(id)animationDelegate;
- (void)doFadeInAnimation;
- (void)doFadeInAnimationWithDelegate:(id)animationDelegate;
@end
```

---

```
UIView-AlertAnimations.m

#import "UIView-AlertAnimations.h"
#import <"QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h">

#define kAnimationDuration  0.2555

@implementation UIView(AlertAnimations)
- (void)doPopInAnimation
{
    [self doPopInAnimationWithDelegate:nil];
}
- (void)doPopInAnimationWithDelegate:(id)animationDelegate
{
    CALayer *viewLayer = self.layer;
    CAKeyframeAnimation* popInAnimation =[CAKeyframeAnimation    
    animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

popInAnimation.duration = kAnimationDuration;
popInAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.9],
                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1],
                         nil];
popInAnimation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], 
                           nil];    
popInAnimation.delegate = animationDelegate;

[viewLayer addAnimation:popInAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"];  
}

- (void)doFadeInAnimation
{
    [self doFadeInAnimationWithDelegate:nil];
}
- (void)doFadeInAnimationWithDelegate:(id)animationDelegate
{
    CALayer *viewLayer = self.layer;
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation 
                                            animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeInAnimation.duration = kAnimationDuration;
    fadeInAnimation.delegate = animationDelegate;
    [viewLayer addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
}
@end



CustomAlertView.m

@implementation CustomAlertView

- (IBAction)show
{
// Retaining self is odd, but we do it to make this "fire and forget"
[self retain];

// We need to add it to the window, which we can get from the delegate
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];
[window addSubview:self.view];

// Make sure the alert covers the whole window
self.view.frame = window.frame;
self.view.center = window.center;

// "Pop in" animation for alert
[alertView doPopInAnimationWithDelegate:self];

// "Fade in" animation for background
[backgroundView doFadeInAnimation];
}

- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    [inputField resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self performSelector:@selector(alertDidFadeOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];



if (sender == self || [sender tag] == CustomAlertViewButtonTagOk)
    [delegate CustomAlertView:self wasDismissedWithValue:inputField.text];
else
{
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customAlertViewWasCancelled:)])
        [delegate customAlertViewWasCancelled:self];
}
```

}

```
 - (void)alertDidFadeOut
{    
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self autorelease];
}
```

**CAAnimation Delegate Methods**

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self.inputField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self dismiss:self];
    return YES;
}
@end


- (IBAction)show
{
// Retaining self is odd, but we do it to make this "fire and forget"
[self retain];

// We need to add it to the window, which we can get from the delegate
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];
[window addSubview:self.view];

// Make sure the alert covers the whole window
self.view.frame = window.frame;
self.view.center = window.center;

// "Pop in" animation for alert
[alertView doPopInAnimationWithDelegate:self];

// "Fade in" animation for background
[backgroundView doFadeInAnimation];
}


- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
[inputField resignFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
self.view.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self performSelector:@selector(alertDidFadeOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

if (sender == self || [sender tag] == CustomAlertViewButtonTagOk)
    [delegate CustomAlertView:self wasDismissedWithValue:inputField.text];
else
{
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customAlertViewWasCancelled:)])
        [delegate customAlertViewWasCancelled:self];
} 
}


- (void)alertDidFadeOut
{    
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self autorelease];
}


- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self.inputField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Finally, we implement one of the text field delegate methods so that when the user presses the return key on the keyboard, it dismisses the dialog.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self dismiss:self];
    return YES;
}
```

At this point, we're done. We can now use this custom alert view exactly the same way we use UIAlertView:

```
 CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc]init];
alert.delegate = self;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Sure this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a view like that yourself.

Easiest way I can think of right off the top of my head would be to create a UIView, then present it modally.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/ and http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/custom-uialertview-with-tableview-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

In iPhone, mostly, `UIPickerView` combined with `UIActionSheet` is used to get inputs from the user where user has to select one option from many.

**An example:**

[image]

Refer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262574/491980) to know how to make it.