# How to programmatically layout an UIButton exactly like this one?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiview, uibutton

I'm using setInputAccessoryView method to add a done button like in the picture below above the keyboard. However, the button shows up very ugly. So, I need your help to programmatically create the same button (color,button type).

[image]

Here's my current code:

```
btDone = [[UIButton alloc] initWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btDone setFrame:CGRectMake(85.0f,0.0f,80.0f,40.0f)];
[btDone setTitle:@"Done"];
[btDone setTitleColor:whiteColor];
[btDone setBackgroundColor:blueColor];
```

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: share your current code.

Comment: this one might help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that black translucent bar is a UIToolBar, then you should add a UIBarButtonItem. The initializer function should be `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` where the first parameter is `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` and the `target` being the object dealing with the action and the `action` the selector that it should execute.