# How to add pickerview to actionsheet for Iphone using Mono Touch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

How to add pickerview to action sheet for next,previous,done buttons on top of actionsheet with tool bar for Iphone using Mono Touch?And how to check mark in picker for selected item .

Comment: Please check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574. I know this is for iOS_SDK & you are looking for **MonoTouch**, I just want you to have a birdEyeView at that link. May be you get some idea. Thx.

Comment: Thank you.I observed it but it is in object-c.Some of properties we have with different keywords so i can't guess those..Any ways i will try.

Comment: You can use Miguel's Rosetta Stone http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html to easily convert ObjectiveC selectors into .NET methods and properties.