# Picker View not appearing on 1st attempt of button click

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uipickerview

I have a button on the extreme right of the cell.

Now I have a picker view which needs to be displayed on button click.

Its working fine with the following code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
    monthPicker.transform = transform;
    [self.view addSubview:monthPicker];
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

But I searched for making picker view hide when it is visible and be shown when no picker view is present,I found out a solution for it.....added the following code to above method:

monthPicker.hidden = [monthPicker isHidden] ? NO : YES;

Now the picker view is not getting displayed on 1st attempt when I click button,but it's working perfect from 2nd attempt and later.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @Padavan should work, but if you want fading effect "in animation", hidden property does not do the job. You have to use UIView.alpha property instead. Here is my sample code for that.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       /////////////////////////////////////////////////
       //    ... Initialize your month picker here    //
       /////////////////////////////////////////////////

       monthPicker.alpha = 0;    
       [self.view addSubview:monthPicker];    
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
    monthPicker.transform = transform;
    monthPicker.alpha = monthPicker.alpha * (-1) + 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Comment: Mr. barley Thanks a ton for the answer,that worked perfect...Thanks a lot once again....

Merry X-Mas in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Are monthPicker initially hidden? When method called first time. If no - it hides and you can't see it. Maybe you need set `monthPicker.hidden=YES` in init method.

Comment: Thanks a alot for the answer...

Yes Mr.Padavan,initially the picker view is hidden,on button click it must appear.... so as you suggested I have initialized the picker view hidden property to YES in the button action method itself,it is showing but not disappearing now on 2nd click...

and also -(id)init method I specified hidden state to YES,but its not working please help me...

Comment: I don't know why you set hidden property to YES in the "button action" as well. As Padavan says, you only have to add the monthPicker.hidden=YES in init method to your original code.

Comment: As a side note, I think you should call [self.view addSubview:monthPicker] in the init method (I prefer in loadView or viewDidLoad though). Otherwise, you are adding the same picker view to the parent view every time you click the button, which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @barley Sorry I was trying to initialise in -(id)initWithNibName method,instead of assigning it in viewDidLoad method,sorry and thanks a lot for the help and rectifying me in right direction :)

Comment: @Padavan sorry that I misunderstood the answer,too cautious about what you said,thanks and I have upvoted your answer and rectified my mistake :D