# Initial and place an UIButton in an UIActionSheet with an UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipickerview, subclass, uiactionsheet

I am implementing picker by [Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how). I tried to replace the UISegmentedControl with a UIButton but it does not working. Could someone remind me why UIButton cannot be shown here?

Thank you.

```
- (IBAction) makeButtonPressed: (id) sender;
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    [actionSheet setTitle:@"Select Make"];
    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque];

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

//  UISegmentedControl *doneButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
//  doneButton.momentary = YES; 
//  doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
//  doneButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
//  doneButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//  [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(makeDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//  [actionSheet addSubview:doneButton];

    UIButton *doneButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(makeDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:doneButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designated initializer for `UIButton` is `+buttonWithType:`. You should create your button with one of the predefined styles, or use `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

```
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRect];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(makeDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[actionSheet addSubview:doneButton];
```