# iPad UIActionSheet not showing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I used code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how) post to display a action sheet in my application. But it shows like

[image]

What will be the reason?

My code to display action sheet is

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 300, 300);

UIView *pickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
pickerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];


UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
closeButton.momentary = YES; 
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];


[actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

[self.view addSubview:actionSheet];
```

Comment: Atleast give some title to buttons. Otherwise it won't show up.

Answer (score 9):

Replace

```
 [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
```

with

```
 [actionSheet showFromRect:btnShare.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

or if you want Action sheet in iPad then try this custom control
https://nodeload.github.com/Arrived/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets/zipball/master

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIActionSheet  showFromRect` or `UIActionSheet  showFromBarButtonItem:` method.

`UIActionSheetDelegate` methods are -

```
 - (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated;
 - (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

example:

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:self.btnShare.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

If you are using for iPhone app use `UIActionSheet showInView` method -

```
- (void)showInView:(UIView *)view;
```

example -

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view.window];
```