# Combobox Image for the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create simple combo box for my app. I've read the following question: [Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

Do you have links for a nice image that I can put on the button that acts like a combobox? I searched the web with no luck, so whoever uses my app doesn't know that this button is actually a combobox.

Thanks.

Comment: how about making them yourselves, like in photoshop or other image editing software. because if you tried using images in the net, it would be like copyright, I think. just a suggestion.

Comment: well, that's a possibility, however, I think that this is such a common image that it's ought to be available for everyone to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's link to some nice iphone kit images:
[iOS 5 GUI PSD (iPhone 4S)](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/ios-5-gui-psd-iphone-4s/&ei=leBaUJ76FtKS0QXboIFo&usg=AFQjCNFQdUjwDOAJ-zn8u5nSIlI6jO0cnA)

If you can't find it there, do what we all do, either design the images yourself or hire a designer :)