# Drop-down list object, like HTML "select" tag

Tags: cocoa-touch, user-interface

Is there any library containing an object to create a drop-down list like an HTML `<select>` for my iPhone app? I have all the values in an array and want to allow the user to choose one.

Comment: Why the downvotes folks? This is a valid question. It may not be a super high level question, but it is still valid none the less.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 not my vote but I assume that googling for dropdownlist objective c will solve the issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would start by looking at the [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) class reference and documentation. There is also links to sample projects on the OSX documentation.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how) for an example of what a UIPickerView looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this github project (disclaimer: I wrote it): https://github.com/daschae/Nine90. The select control attempts to deliver the same experience as mobile Safari. It has served me well, and I'm open to feedback regarding its fitness for your purpose.