# iOS: Hiding UIView objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to implement a `UIDatePicker`on Storyboard. As you would expect, the date picker can't be on screen when the view first loads so I have to write the custom code to move it off screen on load. Here's the code...

```
- (void)hideDatePicker
{
  CGRect newRect = self.datePicker.frame;
  CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake( 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
  newRect.origin = newOrigin;

  self.datePicker.frame = newRect;
}
```

I am currently calling this method in `viewDidLoad`.

When I run the app, the date picker is still on the bottom of the screen, disgustingly taking up half the screen...

Comment: What is self.datePicker when you do this. Maybe you forgot to link the picker to your code and self.datePicker == nil.

Comment: Do not call it in viewDid Load: if you want to load it later.Maybe call the method on a button action or hide it before and then make it unhidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to implement it inside an `UIActionSheet`, a not-so-difficult and elegant solution. Check out this question that will provide you a brief explanation and the necessary code. [Add UIPickerView & a Button in Action sheet - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how)

Answer (score 1):

In `-viewDidLoad:` you can't be sure that all IBOutlets are instantiated and all geometry set, so you better call your method in `-view[Will/Did]Appear:` if you're using any geometry transformations.
And it's easier to hide with `hidden` property

`yourView.hidden = YES;`