# Creating a Selection Menu using Cocoa Touch and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, menu

I'm creating a single view application using Cocoa Touch. I need a menu to appear with a selection of different themes for that single view, and Ive been wondering what the best approach is, and how to achieve that.

Should I create a Master-Detail view? And if so how do I get the detail view to be the initial screen that the App loads. But I'm not sure if this is the best approach to take.

Ive also been looking at things like this [pop over menu](http://www.binpress.com/app/popover-menu-for-ios/604), but Id rather learn how to achieve this kind of thing myself, than just buy an off the shelf solution. Is there any class in Cocoa Touch which offers similar functionality? They have obviously built this menu from scratch using Core Graphics, but is there an easier way to achieve this type of menu, perhaps using a group of UIButtons for example?

Code examples would be greatly appreciated, but I am really looking for the best way to tackle this problem, so I know which Frameworks to familiarize myself with.

TIA

Comment: This question is very general. You're asking about design and implementation at the same time. I recommend you break it up. Start with the design problem. When that's solved, go on to implementation.

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Are you asking how to load the detailView on app launch or how to customize the popover like in the example you mentioned ?

Comment: I am looking for the best approach, in objective c/cocoa touch, to do a selection menu (specifically for selecting different themes, so the menu should be visual in nature), and hopefully how i would go about implementing this. Should I be using a Master-Detail view? a UITableView or UICollectionView? Should I use an ActionSheet, or should I use a UINavigationController? Or is there something else I should use instead? With so many different approaches, I am wondering which one is most applicable to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to create a grid of buttons that could be used to switch between the different themes.

Without knowing more about what you want out of your selection menu, how many themes you have, how you want it to display etc. it’s difficult to suggest one method over another. But because `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is a pre-defined `UICollectionViewLayout` provided by Apple to display `UIViews` in a grid arrangement, it could be a good way of tackling this problem.

Here is how you would implement a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectioViewFlowLayout`:

**Header file**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> {
    UICollectionView * themeSelection;
}
```

**Implementation File**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    themeSelection =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [themeSelection setDataSource:self];
    [themeSelection setDelegate:self];

    [themeSelection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [self.view addSubview: themeSelection];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 15;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Each cell is a theme that could be selected

    return cell;
}     

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a UINavigationController and pushing an UITableViewController with a list of themes on the navigation stack?

You are not limited in the number of themes you can offer and it should be pretty easy to do.

Or you could use [UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] with modalTransitionStyle set to UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal.

Comment: Interesting. Can you go into any more detail about the UINavigationController method you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of themes is less than or equal to six, you can use a UIActionSheet with a couple of buttons. In your view controller, handle a tap on a "Choose Theme" button thing with this kind of code:

```
UIActionSheet* as = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Theme" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Theme 1", @"Theme 2", @"Blue Theme", @"etc."];
[as showInView:[self view]];
```

At the top of your .h file, next to the class definition, add this:

```
<UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

And in the .m file ad a method like this:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet*)as clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
  switch(index) {
    case 0:
      //It was theme 1
      break;
    case 1:
      //It was Theme 2
      break;
    case 3:
      //It was blue theme
      break;
    //And so on...
  }
}
```

Replace the comments with switching to the selected theme.

**Note:** if you have more than six themes, you are going to want something more like the solution discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how) SO question on UIPickerViews in action sheets.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for do this. such like add UITableView to UIActionSheet and display 
actionSheet on specific button.
also UIPopOverViewController is best for do this type of work.

Following are useful source of Code that might be helpful in your case:

https://github.com/nacho4d/Accordion

https://github.com/kyoshikawa/ZPopoverController

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will check them out. UIPopOverViewController seem to be a good solution to what I am after, but it is an iPad only feature which is a shame as I am developing the App for both iPads and iPhones.