# close UIPickerView by Donebutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have this code. UIPickerView for Textfield.
I would like to desigh so that
when user edit `UITextField`,`UIPickerView` and `donebutton` are displayed,
`UIPickerView` is closed by pushing `donebutton`.

Problem is `doneButton` is not displayed. 
So,Picker cannot be closed.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UIPickerView *picker1;
    NSString *pic1_str;
}
@synthesize textField1;
@synthesize textField2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textField1.delegate = self;

    picker1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    picker1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 216);
    picker1.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    picker1.delegate = self;
    picker1.dataSource = self;
    picker1.tag = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:picker1];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        [self showPicker1];
        return NO;
}

- (void)showPicker1 {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    picker1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 204, 320, 216);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (!self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem) {
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)];
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)done:(id)sender {
    [self hidePicker];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
}

- (void)hidePicker {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    picker1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 216);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Any idea on how I could fix it?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262574/add-uipickerview-a-button-in-action-sheet-how

Comment: where is done button located, behind picker view or where??

Comment: did ur navigation bar displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do that by setting the `inputView` of the `UITextField` object:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.inputView = _pickerView;
    textField.inputAccessoryView = self.accessoryView_;

    return YES;
}
```

where the property accessoryView_ could be instantiated with:

```
self.accessoryView_ = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _pickerView.frame.size.width, 40)];

        [(UIToolbar *) self.accessoryView_ setItems:@[
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPicker)]
         ]];
```

somewhere in your code (viewDidLoad would be a good place to do it)

dismissPicker is simply

```
- (void) dismissPicker
{
    [_textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Of course you have to keep a reference to the `textField` with a property or an ivar

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you have the problem to show the "Done" button on navigation bar (right side). The navigation item would not be able to work properly if the current `UIViewController` is not part of the `UINavigationController` hierarchy or not initialised with `UINavigationController` as rootViewController.

You can confirm this via the below code snippet, if it works then view controller is part of the `UINavigationController`, if not then you should have to check your UINavigation hierarchy.

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"done", @"Done")
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                            target:self action:@selector(doneAction)];
```