# iPhone, object on a picket sheet how do I detect when the action sheet is closed / dismissed?

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

How can I determine when an action sheet has closed or has been dismissed ?

I've followed this topic [Fitting a UIDatePicker into a UIActionSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349858/fitting-a-uidatepicker-into-a-uiactionsheet) and added a picker view to an action sheet. However the didSelectRow event is called while action sheet is still open.

I want to update some data in my table view by changing some sql and re-querying my database, but having it refresh each click is slow, I want to refresh when the action sheet it gone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store selected date value in some temporary variable. Then update your table view on action dismissed action (e.g. in actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex: delegate method)