# UIDatePicker inside actionsheet is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I'm trying to show UIDatePicker inside action sheet but its not working.

Here's my code.  On button click I've written this code

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIView *datePickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
[datePickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

[datePickerView addSubview:datePicker];
[alertController.view addSubview:datePicker];

UIAlertAction* alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault                                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {


}];

[alertController addAction:alertAction];

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

[alertAction setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
```

This is the updated code.  While running in simulator it is working fine but working in device I can't able to click the OK button (uialertaction)... While trying to click OK button picker is scrolling continuously

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349858/fitting-a-uidatepicker-into-a-uiactionsheet

Comment: Answer given in above link was not working for me.  Its showing action sheet but not the picker @Cyph3r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.  This code works fine in device... Thanks for help

```
   UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

CGRect pickerFrame = datePicker.frame;
pickerFrame.size.height = datePicker.frame.size.height - 50;
datePicker.frame = pickerFrame;

[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[alertController.view addSubview:datePicker];

UIAlertAction* alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault                                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

}];

[alertController addAction:alertAction];

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

As `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in `iOS 8.3` you need to go with Apple provided documents and guideline to add `DatePicker` in your screen.

Apple had introduced the use of inline date picker (like Calendar app date picker).

Use below github Code for Inline Date Picker

**Link :** https://github.com/DylanVann/DatePickerCell

**For reference :** [iOS 7 - How to display a date picker in place in a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios-7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view)